# Coefficients in the Generalized Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Given a series of polynomials ${p_n}\left( x \right), n = 0,1,2, \ldots ,$ that are orthogonal in a range $[a,b]$, you can approximate a continuous function on that range as $$f(x) \sim\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} c_i p_n(x)$$

However, how would you find the series of coefficients $c_i$ for the series? For example, use the Laguerre or Hermite polynomials

Comment: You take inner products; that’s the point of having the polynomials be orthogonal.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Could you be a bit more specific? An equation, perhaps?

Comment: If the polynomials $p_n(x)$ are orthogonal with respect to a weight $w(x)$ on $[a, b]$, which means that if we define $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_a^b f(x) \overline{g(x)} w(x) \, dx$ then $\langle p_i, p_j \rangle = 0$ if $i \neq j$ and is positive otherwise, then the coefficient of $c_n$ in the expansion of a function $f$ is $\frac{ \langle f, p_n \rangle}{\langle p_n, p_n \rangle}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh, ok, I think I get it. However, since for Laguerre polynomials, $\langle p_i, p_j \rangle=1$, would it just be $\langle f, p_n \rangle$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Also, wouldn't the conjugate of $g(x)$, be just $g(x)$?

Comment: Yes, and yes if you're working with real polynomials, but you could work with complex ones if you wanted to approximate complex functions (you mentioned "generalized Fourier series").

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ok, thank you. Can you put this in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @QiaochuYuan's comment:

If the polynomials $p_n(x)$ are orthogonal with respect to a weight $w(x)$ on $[a,b]$, which means that if we define $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_a^b f(x) \overline{g(x)} w(x) \, dx$ then $\langle p_i, p_j \rangle = 0$ if $i \neq j$ and is positive otherwise, then the coefficient of $c_n$ in the expansion of a function $f$ is $\frac{ \langle f, p_n \rangle}{\langle p_n, p_n \rangle}$.

**EDIT**: For future reference, I found [this article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFourierSeries.html) that explained it perfectly-- don't know how I forgot it.